# testing void method with EasyMock

Tags: junit, easymock

I need to test sorting class which takes a array of certain interface type. The interface only has one function which only compare an object and return some int value. I am trying to use easymock to test it with jUnit. I am stuck with two problems. 
First, I need to assign some value to the each mock object that I created for the given interface.

```
mock[0] = EasyMock.createMock(CompareValue.class);
```

How can I assign some value to mock[0]? The interface CompareValue only has following method:

```
int compareVal(Object obj);
```

the object is going to be a CompareValue type in the sorting class

Second, I only have static void method in the class which takes a list and modifies it but dont return anything. I am not suppose to change any code in interface or class.I dont know how to retrieve that modified list to check if it has been sorted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Override the getter instead of assigning a value to the mock.

```
expect(mock[0].getValue()).andRetun(yourValue);
```

Comment: there is no getValue() method in the interface. Is there any way in which I can directly assign value to the mock object?

Comment: I think the only possible way is to implement an inner class

Comment: Can you please provide some details of the CompareValue class.